# What happens to recruited creations that you then Dismiss?

Tags: geneforge-2

In GF2, there are pre-existing creations in the world that you can recruit, typically by passing a Leadership or Shaping check. Unlike your own creations, they cannot be controlled, but neither do they lower your maximum Essence while in play.

Unfortunately, there are some circumstances where you don't want them. With no way to say "stay where you are", your only option is to Dismiss them, which produces the message "it walks off, no doubt to return to where it came from".

However, if you then go back to the place where you recruited it, it's not there.

Where, if anywhere, do they go? If you Dismiss a creation, is there any way to recruit it again? Or is it gone for good?